# how to extract data in specific format using .format method in Python

Tags: python

I have a tuple:

```
exam_st_date = (11, 12, 2014)
```

I must to extract the date in format:

```
The examination will start from : 11 / 12 / 2014
```

And I must use `.format` method to accomplish this task.

It works if:

```
>>> exam_st_date = (11, 12, 2014)
>>> print("The examination will start from : {} / {} / {} ".format(exam_st_date[0], exam_st_date[1], exam_st_date[2]))
The examination will start from : 11 / 12 / 2014
```

But why it does not work if:

```
>>> exam_st_date = (11, 12, 2014)
>>> print("The examination will start from : {} / {} / {} ".format(exam_st_date()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
..., line 7, in <module>
    print("The examination will start from : {} / {} / {} ".format(exam_st_date()))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Please explain the optimal way to solve this task.

Comment: Why do you think `exam_st_date()` being a tuple should behave as a function?

Comment: ^ follow up: the brackets are making it behave as a function when it isn't one, and hence the 'tuple is not callable error'

Comment: `exam_st_date` is a tuple, not a function.  It cannot be called as you are doing via `exam_st_date()` which is like typing `(11, 12, 2014)()`.

Comment: I would recommend going through datetime.date so you get all the features and validation of an actual date library. And it has format functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best you could do is

```
print("The examination will start from : {} / {} / {} ".format(*exam_st_date)) # unpacking the tuple
```

using `datetime` module which I will recommend

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime(*exam_st_date[::-1])
print("The examination will start from : {} / {} / {} ".format(dt.day,dt.month,dt.year))
```

Comment: You may want to elaborate on unpacking a tuple with *

Comment: [python3 docs: unpack operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)